# Reloading Modules In Embedded Python Interpreter

Tags: python, c, cpython, pythoninterpreter

We are writing a C application that allows people to load a python module and call a function in it. The function is called when the user requests that it be run (once) through a user-interface action. The Python interpreter is embedded inside the application to avoid data communication costs of inter-process communication.

A module loaded in the interpreter can be modified externally by the user and the application is expected to reload the module when the user requests the module to be run the next time.

Given that the python module reload API doesn't reload the dependent submodules, the only way we can achieve this is by unloading the module. To do this, we use the *RollbackImporter* described [here](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/notes/reloading.html).

**Is unloading and reloading modules from an embedded Python interpreter in this way safe?**